# Big Cartel - Site Title

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

Worked on my page throughout the weekend and still have a few lingering items I am struggling with. The site is http://johnathonpowers.bigcartel.com/.

The home page and main product page both have a different font size for the "Johnathon Powers" at the top of the page. I have search and searched through the CSS looking for all the font sizes and changing them really large, saving, then reverting back if they don't seem to change anything or change something other than the title. I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this.

Another thing while discussing this title is the option to have it at the top of the page. Would this be extremely complicated to have the header (with links automatically inserted by bigcartel) below the title? Here is an example I found when looking at drop-down menu options. http://littlefawn.bigcartel.com/ 
edit: I just realized that this example is one I stumbled upon from someone who sells themes and layouts for bigcartel. I truly hope I am not stepping on anyone's toes by trying to do this myself/using that example.

Comment: You want to change the font-size from nav-bar on top?

Comment: Homepage is H1 and other pages are H2.

Comment: @aldanux No, I want to change the font style/size of the text "Johnathon Powers" which is different on the home page and main product page from all the other pages on the website.

Comment: @billymoat Thanks for the information. I will try looking at this in the html section as opposed to the CSS for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Luna theme has a "quickfit" plugin that adjusts the header font size with an inline style rule, based on your screen size (mostly to make it look better on mobile devices). You should be able to add this to the bottom of your CSS and specify whatever font size you'd like:

```
#site_header header #store_name { 
  font-size:36px !important;
}
```

Otherwise you could consider uploading a header logo in Customize Design > Customize which will replace your header text.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. I will go back and remove what I added in the CSS code and play around with this at the end of the coding. Curious though with it as it is now I got the fonts to match (IDK why) when I added in `padding-top: 100px`. It seemed to just all work. 


Although (being picky now) the block of text moves up and down between the home page (or any page) and a specific product page (clicking on a product). Not sure if you see the vertical movement. I will keep working on this. On the home stretch and really learning a ton. Thanks again!

Comment: EDIT: NVM, deleted my changes and used your code instead. Works 100%. All pages are equal and the same now. Thanks man. I feel bad getting so much help around here and not able to help in return. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

The larger JP is governed by the CSS ID `#site_header header #store_name a` on the other pages JP has a simple `<h1>` tag.

Comment: Ahh ok. Well that would explain it. I guess I will need to figure out how to get the about me, individual product pages, FAQ, and contact pages to be governed all by the same CSS ID as opposed to being h1 tags. This will be messy I think.
Thanks for your assistance and help.